# Variance of a difference variable

Tags: self-study, correlation, variance, covariance, differences

I have a question I'm quite struggling with.
$\newcommand{\Var}{{\rm Var}} \newcommand{\Cov}{{\rm Cov}}$

Let's say I have variable $x_1$, and I know that $x_2=x_1+d$, with $d$ being a random variable representing the difference between the two.
I know only $x_1$, and the correlation between $x_1$ and $x_2$. I don't know anything else about $x_2$.

I need to calculate the variance of diff, given the variance of $x_1$, and $r_{12}$. Now, from the formula of $r_{12}$ I got to this point:

$$\Var_{d} =\frac{(\Var_{1}+\Cov_{1,d})^{2}}{(r_{12}\cdot \sqrt{\Var_{1}})^{2}}-\Var_1-2\Cov_{1,d}$$

Note that when $\Cov_{1,a}=0$, the equation is simplified to:
$$\Var_{d} =\frac{\Var_1}{r_{12}^2}-\Var_1$$

The question is basically - how can I use the pretty complicated formula above, or other formulas, to derive the variance of $d$, when it is no independent from $x_1$. That is if I have $r_{12}$, $r_{1d}$, and $\Var_1$ - what is the variance of $d$ (with $d = x_2-x_1$).

Comment: My interpretation of your question. x2=x1+d. You know $\rho =$ coreelation(x1,x2), and Var(x1). So $Var(x2) = Var(x1) + Var(d) + 2\rho\sqrt{Var(x1)Var(x2)}$. If you knew Var(x2), you could solve for Var(d) or vice versa.  You don't have enough information to solve for Var(d) unless you know something more, such as Var(x2).  Or put another way, there are an infinite number of combinations of Var(x2) and Var(d) which are consistent with the information you have.

Comment: consider adding the [tag:self-study] tag after reading its wiki.

Comment: @idif could you disambiguate the question regarding what's actually known?

Comment: Sure, sorry for being unclear. What is known is Var(x), cor1d, and cor12.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is basically - how can I use the pretty complicated formula above, or other formulas, to derive the variance of d, when it is no independent from x1. That is if I have **r12**, **r1d**, and **Var1** - what is the variance of d (with d = x2-x1).

$$Var(d) = Var(x_1)+Var(x_2)-2\cdot \rho_{1,2}\cdot\sqrt{Var(x_1)\cdot Var(x_2)}$$

Analogously

$$Var(x_2) = Var(x_1) + Var(d) + 2\cdot \rho_{1,d}\cdot\sqrt{Var(x_1)\cdot Var(d)}$$

Summing both

$$0=2\cdot Var(x_1)
+2\cdot \rho_{1,d}\cdot\sqrt{Var(x_1)\cdot Var(d)}
-2\cdot \rho_{1,2}\cdot\sqrt{Var(x_1)\cdot Var(x_2)}
$$

Now we divide by $2\cdot \sqrt{Var(x_1)}$

$$0=\sqrt{Var(x_1)}
+\rho_{1,d}\cdot\sqrt{Var(d)}
-\rho_{1,2}\cdot\sqrt{Var(x_2)}
$$

$$\sqrt{Var(x_1)}
+\rho_{1,d}\cdot\sqrt{Var(d)}
=\rho_{1,2}\cdot\sqrt{Var(x_2)}
$$

---

Using a solver I got to the following solutions:

$$Var(d) = Var(x_1)\cdot
\left(\frac{\rho_{1,d}(\rho_{1,2}^2-1) \pm \rho_{1,2}\cdot\sqrt{1-\rho_{1,2}^2}\cdot\sqrt{1-\rho_{1,d}^2}}{\rho_{1,d}^2-\rho_{1,2}^2}
\right)^2$$

---

Here's an example in R.

```
#Our variables
x1 = rnorm(100)+1
x2 = rnorm(100)+2
#Our difference
d = x2 - x1

#Let's call these by letters for brevity
a = sqrt(var(x1))
b = cor(x1,d)
c = cor(x1,x2)

res1 = ((a*(b*(c^2-1)-c*sqrt(1+b^2*c^2-b^2-c^2)))/(b^2-c^2))^2
res2 = ((a*(b*(c^2-1)+c*sqrt(1+b^2*c^2-b^2-c^2)))/(b^2-c^2))^2
```

Check `res1` and `res2`, and if either match `var(d)`

Comment: You seem to be making use of $\rho_{1,d}$, which per my interpretation is not assumed to be known. So basically, back in the same (or "equivalent") boat as per my comment on the question.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Isn't it? I think the question makes clear both $cor(x_1,x_2)$ and $cor(x_1,d)$ are known.

Comment: The question is ambiguously written. Per the beginning, you don't know it. Per the end, you do. So I guess your interpretation is reasonable.

Comment: +1.  Consider completing your answer by writing down the implied formula for $\operatorname{Var}(d)$ explicitly.

Comment: @whuber It's quite lenghty. While I haven't checked it I arrived using a solver at
$$
\sqrt{Var(d)} = \frac{\sqrt{Var(x_1)}\rho_{1,d}(\rho_{1,2}^2-1)
\pm \sqrt{Var(x_1)} \rho_{1,2}\sqrt{1 + \rho_{1,d}^2\rho_{1,2}^2-\rho_{1,2}^2-\rho_{1,d}^2}}
{\rho_{1,d}^2-\rho_{1,2}^2}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Firebug you're correct to assume that both correlations are known. Let me test your answer and play with it for a bit. Trying using a solver on the formula I've written above gave me a much more complicated formula than yours - so that definitely helps. Not sure how to approach to 'two possible answers' thing yet, though.

Comment: I've just tested the solution by simulating some data in R and testing the correlation matrix, and it seems to work just great. Thanks! I noticed though that it works only when r1d < r12. I was wondering if you might have any ideas of why is it the case?